# How can I have getdate() as a header for my column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Example:

```
SELECT GETDATE() AS GETDATE()
```

Comment: Shouldn't you just set something like SELECT GETDATE() AS 'GETDATE()'

Comment: Why not give a name that is not so silly. Something like RunDate or something that makes sense.

Comment: i am not a SQL developer but thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the obvious why, here's how:

```
SELECT GETDATE() as "GETDATE()"
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the column alias in square brackets **`[]`**.

**Query**

```
Select GETDATE() as [GETDATE()];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT GETDATE() as 'GETDATE()'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Alias name as same as Column name :

```
 SELECT GETDATE() as [GETDATE()]

 OR

 SELECT GETDATE() as "GETDATE()"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use quoting marks.

```
SELECT GETDATE() as [GETDATE()]
```

or

```
SELECT GETDATE() as "GETDATE()"
```